# How To Trigger A Windows Task When Phone Is Plugged In

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-task-scheduler

I use this awesome tool [gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) for reverse tethering, i.e. using the internet connection from my Windows PC on my phone.

Now, I would like to start this tool automatically, when the phone is plugged in into the PC. And probably the best idea to do so is to use Windows Task Scheduler. However, how can I create a trigger for "mobile phone plugged in via USB into PC"?

[image]

Comment: There's a parameter for that: `gnirehtet autorun`

Comment: So, I need to create a .cmd file with the content of "@gnirehtet.exe autorun @pause" which I start with Windows? The current .cmd file I start has the content "@gnirehtet.exe run @pause"